# Why no silver background on div element?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code.

```css
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> .red-text {
  color: red;
}
h2 {
  font-family: Lobster, Monospace;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Monospace;
}
.thick-green-border {
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.smaller-image {
  width: 100px;
}
.silver-background {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
 <h2 class="red-text">CatPhotoApp</h2>
<p>Click here for <a href="#">cat photos</a>.</p>
<a href="#">
  <img class="smaller-image thick-green-border" alt="A cute orange cat lying on its back. " src="fcc-relaxing-cat">
</a>
<div class="silver-background">
  <p>Things cats love:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>cat nip</li>
    <li>laser pointers</li>
    <li>lasagna</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Top 3 things cats hate:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>flea treatment</li>
    <li>thunder</li>
    <li>other cats</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<form action="/submit-cat-photo">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor" checked>Indoor</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor">Outdoor</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="personality" checked>Loving</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="personality">Lazy</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="personality">Energetic</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="cat photo URL" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

An error info occur when to submit it.
Your div element should have a silver background.

My div element is already in silver background in the right of the attatchment.
It is no use for me to refresh my browser or reboot my pc.
Maybe it is a bug on freecodecamp platform,i can't find any bug on my html text.
The link can't paste here,so can't see the photo when to run the code.
[image]

Comment: why do you have <link> element inside your css?

Comment: In the live demo in your question, it is silver. You need to provide a test case that allows us to reproduce the problem before we can tell what the problem is. See [MCVE]

Comment: This doesnt so much look like a problem with your code but a problem with its submission. You'd probably have better results in contacting someone at freecodecamp about this than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reboot into my win7,for the same html code to open with chrome ,the error info vanish.Different effects on different browser same simple html code,maybe it can be called a bug on freecodecamp platform.

Answer (score -1):

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").addClass("silver-background");
    });
});

</script>


</head>
```

i have used jquery for this. i have added a function for click which add a class to div when button is clicked. just add this to your head and it will work fine.